# Horizontally center part page in memoir with working reference

Tags: memoir, labels, parts, adjustwidth

For my memoir document, I want to have a quite large outer margin. This has the side effect of putting the text on Part pages quite far towards the spine - something that I would like to remedy.

I have tried to use memoir's `\adjustwidth*`-functionality. This centers the text nicely, but has the undesired effect of messing up labeling/referencing. After redefinitions, calling `\Pref`  just prints `Part`, with no number.

Centered, but broken labeling.

[image: Centered]
[image: Part reference not printing correctly]

Not centered, working labeling.

[image: Not centered]
[image: Part reference printing correctly]

MWE (comment ll. 14 & 15 to see non-centered, but labeling working)

```
\documentclass[twoside,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Margins
\sideparmargin{outer}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{2.55}
\checkandfixthelayout

% Length for centering
\newlength{\mylength} % calcualted at start of document. Used for centering stuff on the page.

%Redefine beofre/after partskip to get centering
\renewcommand*{\beforepartskip}{\vspace*{0.21\textheight}\begin{adjustwidth*}{\mylength}{-\mylength}}
\renewcommand*{\afterpartskip}{\end{adjustwidth*}\vfil} %\newpage

\begin{document}
\calccentering{\mylength}
\part{First}
\label{part:first}

\chapter{Oh, no!}
\label{chap:ohno}

\lipsum 

\part{Second}

\chapter{Haha}

A reference to \Pref{part:first}, \Cref{chap:ohno}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

*Delete* To me it seems that the `\label` problem is that it occurs within the `adjustwidth` environment, although why that should be a problem beats me. *End delete*

I do not understand why there should be this problem. As my late Father-in-Law was fond of saying "It's a mystery, mate!"

However, it all seems to work if you put the part label in the `part` macro's argument. Like

```
\part{First\label{part:first}}
```

instead of

```
\part{First}
\label{part:first}


% mempartprob.tex  SE 638733

\documentclass[twoside,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Margins
\sideparmargin{outer}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{2.55}
\checkandfixthelayout

% Length for centering
\newlength{\mylength} % calcualted at start of document. Used for centering stuff on the page.

%Redefine beofre/after partskip to get centering
\renewcommand*{\beforepartskip}{\vspace*{0.21\textheight}\begin{adjustwidth*}{\mylength}{-\mylength}}
\renewcommand*{\afterpartskip}{\end{adjustwidth*}}%\vfil} %\newpage

\begin{document}
\calccentering{\mylength}
\tableofcontents
\part{First\label{part:first}}
%\label{part:first}

\chapter{Oh, no!}
\label{chap:ohno}

\lipsum[1]

\section{But yes}

\lipsum[2]

\part{Second%}
\label{part:second}}

\chapter{Haha}

A reference to \Pref{part:first}, \Cref{chap:ohno}

This is part \ref{part:second} which was preceeded by a \verb!\section!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. 

I am not sure I understand your point about the `\label` appearing within `\adjustwidth` - as far as I understand, the label in my code appears **after** `\afterpartskip`, so outside of `\adjustwidth`. What could be happening, though is that the marking of the chapter becomes local in some way. This would be consistent with other behavior I have observed, where it picked up the last section before the Part (e.g. `\Pref{part2}`, would print as `Part X.Y`, where `X.Y` is the section defined before the Part).

Comment: @ChristofferØstfeldt You are right. I have deleted the portion of my answer regarding `\label` within `adjustwidth`. Putting the `\label` in the `\part` argument seems to cure your section/part problem.